# Unable to set action for UITabbarItem Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

i need to set action for my `UITabbar`, As when i click my tabbaritem it should go to an action which i am having in another viewcontroller.

but it is redirecting to `UITableview`

here is my code -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// create our table view controller that will display our store list    
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[EzMasterViewController alloc] init];


// create the navigation controller that will hold our store list and detail view controllers and set the store list as the root view controller
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
[navController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Home"];
[navController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"53-house.png"]];


SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];


// create the navigation controller that will hold our store list and detail view controllers and set the store list as the root view controller
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[navController1.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Scan"];
[navController1.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"195-barcode.png"]];

ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];


// create the navigation controller that will hold our store list and detail view controllers and set the store list as the root view controller
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];
[navController2.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Map"];
[navController2.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"07-map-marker.png"]];

// add our view controllers to an array, which will retain them
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, navController1,navController2, nil];

// add our array of controllers to the tab bar controller
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

// set the tab bar controller as our root view controller    
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

By clicking on `SecondViewController` tabbaritem it should redirect to the action,
where the action is in `FirstViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider implementing the [UITabBarControllerDelegate's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) two methods:

```
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

Comment: hi, can u give me a full details plz, in FirstViewController i am having a buttonaction i want to call that one in appdelegate,