# suffering with UITabbaritems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

For some days now I have been suffering with `UITabBarItem`s.

I have done my application in programatical way, not using Interface Builder.
I have both a `UINavigationBar` and a `UITabbarController`.

From home page when I have proceed with navigation (I mean when I move to next page) at that time when i have clicked next tab item (Contact), and again when I have clicked the home button, it is not moving to home page, it is remaining with the previous page where I left that one, it is not redirecting to home page at all,

I have placed the `UITabbarController`-code in my application delegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
viewController *vc = [[viewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[navController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Home"];
[navController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]];

viewController1 *vc1 = [[viewController1 alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
[navController1.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Contact"];
[navController1.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact.png"]];

viewController2 *vc2 = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
[navController2.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Info"];
[navController2.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, navController1,navController2,  nil];
 _tabBarController.delegate = self;
[_tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

[self.window setRootViewController:_tabBarController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
```

I didn't used these methods:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Please give me suggestions, or something that may be useful to me.

Comment: I am unsure I understand your question because of the way you have put it. Can you simplify it for me? What do you want?

Comment: Is this not the same as a question you have already asked? Being unable-to-set-action-for-uitabbaritem-programmatically. I believe you have made a duplicate of your own question.

Comment: i got tabbar's, now i got another problem,so i have asked again

Comment: repost of [Unable to set action for UITabbarItem Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926391/unable-to-set-action-for-uitabbaritem-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default behaviour of UITabbarController is, that if you tap a tab and this tab contains a navigationcontroller, you get the page which is on top of the navigationcontrollers viewcontroller-stack.

To avoid this you have to popToRootViewController when you tap on the tab.

If you implement

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
    [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 }
```

it should do the trick.

Comment: i think no need of "navigationController" [viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];